# How to display date only from datetime type into datetime object

Tags: c#

In string array I have date field, which I want to format for date only and bind it to date time object.

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { 
  "Mahesh Chand", 
  "Mike Gold", 
  "Raj Beniwal", 
  "Praveen Kumar", 
  "7/10/1974 7:10:24 AM" 
};

DateTime dateFromString = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[4]);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Am not getting only date. still am getting date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { 
  "Mahesh Chand", 
  "Mike Gold", 
  "Raj Beniwal", 
  "Praveen Kumar", 
  "7/10/1974 7:10:24 AM" };

DateTime dateFromString = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[4]);

string dt= DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

in this way you will get date as string, but if you want only date part as `DateTime` type then it isn't possible because in `DateTime` type if you don't specify any time then it will automatically add a default time as `12:00:00 AM(00:00:00)` in `DateTime`

**Update**

you can use like this for all culture

```
string dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or you can use simply like this

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { 
  "Mahesh Chand", 
  "Mike Gold", 
  "Raj Beniwal", 
  "Praveen Kumar", 
  "7/10/1974 7:10:24 AM" };

string dateFromString = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[4]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks reply....it throwing exception - The best overload method match for "system.datetime.parseExact/(string,string, system.IformatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: see my update and also make sure your `strArray[4]` have correct date string as `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Thanks rehman for posting reply.....actually i have a datatable with sorting capabilities. If i convert into date formating into string i cannot perform sorting on datatable.

Comment: so in this case you always have 12:00:00 AM as default time

Comment: you can get day, month and year past from date as this way  `dateFromString.Day` month as `dateFromString.Month` and year `dateFromString.Year` and then you can sort using this

Answer (score 1):

You can take only the `Date` without `Time` from a `DateTime` object in this way:

```
DateTime dateFromString = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[4]);
var onlyDate = dateFromString.Date;
// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(onlyDate .ToString("d"));
```

[More info on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this will add 12:00:00 AM as time by default

Comment: You can never have a `DateTime` without a time, it's in the name. Your only choice is to use string formatting and either store it as a String or parse it each time you want to display it. I still think @meorfi answer is correct, it just needs the parsing section adding in