# How do I prevent `DateTime.ParseExact();` from returning time

Tags: c#, datetime

Am using `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();` to change a date in a number format to a date, I ado get the date but it also returns the time part but I would like it to be the date only my, here is my code below.

```
String date = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
Label9.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

for **Input** : 940226 i get the **output**: 02/26/1994 00:00:00  I want to remove the time part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display date only from datetime type into datetime object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787738/how-to-display-date-only-from-datetime-type-into-datetime-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, while it is of course possible to use a [custom date/time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), for the sake of globalization I suggest you use one of the methods that return the date as string based on the system's current culture information. Like for example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Label9.Text = date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Yes, this gives the short date string as defined by the current culture. ___If___ you want the invariant-culture short date representation in all cases, you may use `date.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read about custom date time formatting on MSDN first :

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

The easiest way to get the date string only is using `ToShortDateString()`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output in the US date format, you can use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

By default `ToString()` output date *and* time.

If you want to display the string in the current culture format, just use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("d");
```

As suggested by @[bixarrio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045462/bixarrio). I suggest you to read about the [different shortcuts that `DateTime.ToString()` accepts.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: Right. Everybody around the world uses US dates.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar OP does. And I'm writing for him. If the next reader doesn't/can't commute the format to get what he want that's not my business.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. Should be `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("d");` which will output only the date in the current culture

Comment: May I suggest `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`? Without the format provider (culture info) in `ToString`, the characters `/` (slashes) present in the last format string will be substituted with the date separator og the current culture of the current thread.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen No! Don't make things worse!! In Germany you'd get 01.11.2016. So should that be the 1st of November or the 11th of January?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I agree, but it depends on what you want. With the invariant culture, the slash `/` will be substituted by itself, a slash. So the period thing is what you get with this answer as it stands now.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Ah, sorry, I misread your comment. I read it as if you *wanted* to replace the "/" by the current culture's format specifier. Actually you're right and the solution provided by this answer has the problem I pointed out in my comment.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you were right about it, I overreacted. My apologies.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub All fine! :-)

Answer (score 0):

use a `dateTimePicker` then change its `Format` property to `short`, you won't have to worry about the passing and formatting either